# chaging max width property of grid in bourbon neat

Tags: html, bourbon, neat

I am using bourbon neat for thee first time. 
what I am trying to do is to set `max-width` property of neat in `_grid.css`
Now I am trying to do it in PX say `700px` but by default its `$max-width: em(1000) !default;`
I tried giving it in PX but it doesn't work. can someone please tell mee where i am doing it wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$max-width: em(1000)` is using a mixin defined in Bourbon that allows you to set a value in pixels and the mixin will convert it to ems. 
so the example `$max-width: em(1000)` is equal to  `$max-width: 1000px`

Just go ahead and change that number to the value you want in pixels and let the mixin do the ems math for you.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I see. I should've been a little more specific.

I'm referring to a different file. So if you've fully installed bitters, you should have a folder in your stylesheet directory named `bitters`.

You want to find the file `stylesheets/bitters/_bitters.scss`

Open that file and it should look like this:

```
// Neat Settings -- uncomment if using Neat
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// @import "neat-helpers"; // or "neat/neat-helpers" when not in Rails
// @import "grid-settings";


// Bitters
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@import "variables";
@import "extends/base";
@import "mixins/base";
@import "typography";
@import "forms";
@import "tables";
@import "lists";
@import "flashes";
```

You see the `@import "grid-settings";` is currently commented out. You'll want to uncomment that.

Then, open that exact file: `stylesheets/bitters/_grid-settings.scss`

And from that file you can now manipulate the `$max-width` variable.

I hope that helps!

Comment: as said by the github manual ive importeed it under my main scss file between bourobn and neat import.

Comment: I see - I should've been more clear. What you're referring to in your last comment is the manifest for your app or site.

Comment: added to main.scss for my website.

Comment: I edited my first answer to be more explicit about the structure of bitters.

Comment: maybe i can explicity write it in the scss file.

Comment: Which scss file are you referring to, the `main.scss` file?

Could you make a gist of your `main.scss`, `_bitters.scss` and `_grid-settings.scss`? Or just paste the code for them here?

I'm wondering about 3 things:

In your initial question, you labeled `_grid-settings.scss` as `_grid.css`. If it has the `.css` suffix, it won't understand the variable, and should be throwing you an error.

You also had `!default` at the end of the `$max-width` variable which you shouldn't need.

And I'm assuming you're wanting the code to read `$max-width: 700px;`. Just making sure you dropped those parens.